# From this expression ax/(b+cx), how can I have x only in the numerator?

Tags: factoring

I have an expression ax/(b+cx) where a, b and c are known but I need to get an expression like this (A/B)* x where A, B may be a, b and c manipulated to get (A/B) x.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Can $A$ or $B$ contain $x$?

Comment: No A and B cannot contain x.

Comment: Then you can't, unless $c=0$ or $a=0$.

Comment: Do you have $\frac{ax}{b+cx}$ equal to something? i.e. do you have an equation involving this expression to manipulate or are you just considering the expression itself.

Comment: Just the expression itself.

Comment: As said by Arnaud, you cannot convert such an expression into the desired form because it is no straight line.

Comment: One may write
$$
\frac{ax}{cx+b}=\frac{a}{c}\cdot\frac{cx}{cx+b}=\frac{a}{c}\cdot\frac{(cx+b)-b}{cx+b}=\frac{a}{c}-\frac{ab}{c(cx+b)}
$$ Is it far from what you want?

Comment: Thank you, but for the particular physics problem that I have it is important to have a constant times x.

Comment: As per Peter's comment, your given expression does not define a linear function of x, so it can't be rewritten the form $Cx+D$ for any constants $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because
$(A/B)x$
gets large in absolute value
for large $x$
(unless $A=0$)
while

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{x}{b+cx}
&=\frac1{c}\frac{cx}{b+cx}\\
&=\frac1{c}\frac{cx+b-b}{b+cx}\\
&=\frac1{c}(1-\frac{b}{b+cx})\\
&=\frac1{c}-\frac{b}{c(b+cx)}\\
\end{array}
$

is bounded for large $x$.